WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Possible timeout in receiving first data from donor in gtid stage
I have deployed Alma Linux 9 and MariaDB 10.11.7 with Galera 4 on two AWS instances and all the ports and firewall rules are open between 2 instances, I set the proper wsrep options and I am still seeing the issue below.
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Possible timeout in receiving first data from donor in gtid stage: exit codes: 124 0

By the way , I have tried the same setup in my local laptop, it worked and SST happens and I am able to form the cluster.
I see issues when deployed in cloud instances..
Can you please assist? I have been debugging this issue since a month.

Unfortunately, in such cases you should provide more data. Logs from all nodes in the cluster (or at least joined and donor, if you know how to identify it - in your case it’s just two nodes so that’s easier). The problem is there are so many potential issues that might be causing this - it is really hard to tell what exactly it is. It can be some sort of a network connectivity, especially if you managed to set it up locally. Have you bootstrapped the first node properly? What’s its wsrep_local_state_comment?
